# Найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных после максимального элемента

Tags: c++

Попалось задание на плюсах,в них совершенно не понимаю,а разбираться,к сожалению, нет времени. Может кто помочь с этой задачей?

> Найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных после максимального
>   элемента.

Comment: почему кто-то за вас должен делать задания?

Comment: Я же не написал,чтобы кто-то мне в обязательном порядке,сделал её или кто-то ДОЛЖЕН сделать.
Попросил помощи,может у кого-то и есть свободные минуты,чтобы помочь мне её сделать.Я думаю,такие ресурсы так и работают,кто-то чего-то не знает,задает вопрос,и ему помогают....

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что домашнее задание надо делать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, допустим, вот основа алгоритма.

```
const int a[] = ...;  // Исходный массив.
int max = a[0];       // Максимальный элемент.
int sum = 0;          // Сумма.

for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i) {
    if (a[i] > max) {
        max = a[i];
        sum = 0;
    }
    else {
        sum += a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.
Все сделал,как в вашем примере,только добавил вывод массива и суммы,паузу в конце.Но ругается на идентификатор cout
В чем может быть проблема?
`#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;`

Comment: @tweeker ХЗ. С такими заголовочными файлами и `using` не должен ругаться. Возможно, точка с запятой где-то пропущена или скобка или ещё что.

Comment: оке,буду искать ошибку

Comment: @tweeker вообще-то stdfax первая строка всегда.

Comment: @pavel Оу,точно,благодарю

Answer (score 5):

Если писать на C++, то следует использовать стандартные алгоритмы, определенные ы языке C++.

В этом случае программа может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    int a[N];

    std::srand((unsigned int)std::time(nullptr));

    std::generate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [=] { return std::rand() % N; });

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int long long sum = std::accumulate(
        std::next(std::max_element(std::begin(a), std::end(a))),
        std::end(a), 0ll);

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть как

```
8 17 16 11 9 10 5 1 3 17 6 17 3 6 4 12 10 11 1 3 
sum = 145
```

В этой программе заполняется массив случайными значениями от 0 до 20, а затем в одну строчку записано, как найти сумму элементов после максимального элемента.

Если вы со стандартными алгоритмами C++ не знакомы, то можете вместо них использовать обычные циклы. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    int a[N];

    std::srand((unsigned int)std::time(nullptr));

    for ( int &x : a ) x = std::rand() % N;

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t max_i = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[max_i] < a[i] ) max_i = i;
    }

    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = max_i + 1; i < N; i++ ) sum += a[i];

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Фактически, эта программа эквивалентна показанной выше.

Имеется одна тонкость, на которую следует обратить внимание. В вашей формулировке задания не сказано, после какого максимального элемента надо искать сумму элементов: после первого максимального элемента или после последнего максимального элемента, так как в последовательности чисел может быть несколько максимальных элементов.

Если нужно найти сумму элементов после последнего максимального элемента, то в этом случае, например, в последней программе с циклами вам следует заменить условие в предложении

```
if ( a[max_i] < a[i] ) max_i = i;
             ^^^
```

на

```
if ( a[max_i] <= a[i] ) max_i = i;
             ^^^^^
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.Использовал ваш пример для ознакомления.
Пытаюсь сделать,чтобы консоль не закрывалась сразу после выполнения.Пишу функцию `getch()`.Но ругается,что "идентификатор не найден".В чем проблема?

Comment: @tweeker Надо включить тот заголовок, где эта функция определена. Эта функция не является стандартной. Вы можете ее заменить на предложение std::cin.get();

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой развернутый ответ.На днях разберусь на вашем примере :)

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
vector<int> z = {1,2,3,10,3,4,5};
cout << accumulate(max_element(z.begin(),z.end())+1,z.end(),0);
```